# Meteor - loginWithPassword just doing nothing on success

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm trying to build a simple Login-Form within Meteor and React framework. User-Management is done somewhere else in the application, so I tried to use Meteors 'loginWithPassword' function.

```
export default class Login extends React.Component{

constructor(props){
    super(props);
}
render() {
    return (

        <div id="login">
            <form method="POST" id="loginForm" className="boxCont">
                <div>
                    <label>Username</label>
                    <input id="mail" type="text" name="mail" placeholder="Please enter your username here"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="And your password here"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button id="signIn" onClick={() => this.handleLogin()} name="signIn" className="btn left">Sign In</button>
                </div>
            </form><a id="forgotpass" href="#">Forgot Your Password?</a>
        </div>
    );
}
handleLogin(){
    Meteor.loginWithPassword({username: 'test@test.com'}, 'test', function (err) {
        console.log(err)
    });

}}
```

If any error comes up while logging in, the function seems to work correct and responds with the expected results ('User not found', 'wrong password' ... ). 
But if the given data is correct, there is neither an error nor is Meteor.user oder userId() defined.

Did i forget to load any properties needed for accounts-password or meteor?

Entry in Users-Db exists like written above.

//edit:

I'm using Flow-Router to authenticate access to specific routes.

```
const exposed = FlowRouter.group( { name: 'exposed' } );
const loggedIn = FlowRouter.group({
    name: 'loggedIn',
    triggersEnter: [ () => {
            if (Meteor.loggingIn() || Meteor.userId()){
                FlowRouter.route = FlowRouter.current();
            }
            if (FlowRouter.route.name === 'auth'){
                Session.set('redirectAfterLogin', FlowRouter.route.path);
            }
            FlowRouter.go('auth');
    }],
});

Accounts.onLogin(() => {
    console.log("onLogin")
    redirect = Session.get('redirectAfterLogin');
    if (redirect !== '/auth'){
        FlowRouter.go(redirect)
    }
});
exposed.route('/auth', {
    name: 'auth', action(params, queryParams){
        ReactLayout.render( Empty, { yield: <Login /> } );
    }
});
exposed.route('/', {
    name: 'Dashboard', action(params, queryParams){
        ReactLayout.render( App, { yield: <Dashboard /> } );
    }
});
```

According to Meteor-docs, the onLogin method should be called after loginWithPassword is triggered. 
I got these snippets from the following tutorial:

https://medium.com/@satyavh/using-flow-router-for-authentication-ba7bb2644f42

Comment: https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html#Meteor-loginWithPassword
user Object or String
Either a string interpreted as a username or an email; or an object with a single key: email, username or id. Username or email match in a case insensitive manner.
'''
Meteor.loginWithPassword({email: 'test@test.com'}, 'test', function (err)
'''

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I've tried it with an set email-prop, too. Getting the same results. If one of the parameters is incorrect/ can't be found, I'm getting the expected error. If both are correct, just nothing happens (even the accounts.login method isn't triggered).

Comment: what does it print if you `console.log(Meteor.user())` ?

Comment: Meteor.user() is returning null, when i call it while rerendering the login-component

Comment: `Meteor.user()` is not defined immediately after login but `Meteor.userId()` is. It can take a small amount of time for the data in `Meteor.user()` to become available on the client.

Comment: Unfortunately, userId() is also null. 
Is anything wrong with this syntax: 
Meteor.loginWithPassword({email: 'a@a.com'}, 'a', function (err) {console.log(err)}, or do I have to specify the server side for the login function, too?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that nothing happens because you are not asking it to do anything.

Shouldn't you do something like

```
this.setState({loggedIn: true})
```

which will trigger your component to re-render, and in your render method you should do something like this:

```
render() {
  if (this.state.loggedIn)
    return <Redirect to="/dashboard" />
```

Assuming you are using React Router v4 and the Redirect component (nicer than `history.push()` )

Comment: I'm actually using Flow Router like in the tutorial mentioned above. If I understand the Accounts-docs correctly, the meteor.user should be set automatically by loginWithPassword(), should't it?